# Reducing Compiled Code Size Dramatically by Factoring-Out a void Pointer

Tags: c, optimization, microcontroller, void-pointers, code-size

I've recently been developing some embedded software in C for a microcontroller, which only has 2kB of Flash memory. Coming to the end of programming, I've been hitting the code limit. Up until now, I've been increasing the level of compiler optimisation when this happens, retesting and then carrying on happily. However, I recently reached the limit of optimisation and with the addition of the last bit of functionality, ran out of memory again. As a result, I had to get the George Foreman out on my source code and drain some fat.

I messed around with reducing some layers of abstraction here and there, which helped matters slightly but not enough. The next thing I saw was that I had the function prototype

```
void process_event(Event event, void *data);
```

which takes as its parameters the event to process and a void pointer that *can* be used to pass additional data to the call. If I didn't need any extra data, I passed `NULL`. This function was written very early on in the development and I realised that I never used `data`, so I factored it out. This one change gave me the compiled code size saving I needed (~100 bytes), and I'm wondering *why*, especially considering I generally passed `NULL` when `process_event` was called?

Comment: How many times was the function called?  What was the code saving achieved by removing an argument?

Comment: The function is called a fair amount (>10 times).

Comment: This probably depends a lot on `Event`, its size and structure. You probably hit a boundary of your architecture, where the additional argument imposed a change on the calling convention. Without `data` "all in registers", with it "spilling on the stack" or something like this.

Comment: You don't really specify what "considerable" means in terms of bytes saved. You gain some just by not having to push the extra argument onto the stack each call.

Comment: This change saved a significant amount of _code_, not stack or other runtime storage? Did you diff the assembler to see what changed?

Comment: You would save the code size needed to push the pointer and possibly restore registers.  Depending on the rest of your code, your MCU may have been able to use the registers more efficiently if it didn't have to manipulate the void* data pointer.

Comment: I don't know the exact saving, as when I couldn't link the application, I was quoted that *x* blocks couldn't be placed into Flash. As a guestimate, I'd say about 100 bytes were saved making this change, knowing that I was over the the 2kB limit and now I'm on 1928 bytes.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Event is an enumeration with 7 entries.

Comment: @EdKing, you'd really would have to look in the documentation of your platform to see that there could be an ABI change for that number of paramenters. Then as already someone else suggested, you'd have to look into the assembler that is produced to learn the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About 100 bytes would probably be in line with the fact that your call site has to pass an extra argument every time the function is called - this will at least involve a clear of a register, and, depending on your chip, storing it on the stack before the call.

It is also possible that this simple reduction of one instruction per call could result in more code being removed, depending exactly on how jumps are implemented, as you might find that some code is now in the range of a jump instruction using a short relative offset rather than a long one. A similar saving could be made when trying to load up constants.